# How to compute specificity on confusion matrix in R?

Tags: r

R-Porgramming: Using the Smarket dataset of the ISLR library, how do I compute (the code) for specificity of the confusion matrix (shown on table(glm.pred, Direction.2005))? Here is my code so far:

```
train = (Year<2005) # Vector of 1250 elements
Smarket.2005 = Smarket[!train,]
dim(Smarket.2005) # 252 observations
Direction.2005 = Direction[!train]

# Refit model using just Lag1 and Lag2
glm.fits = glm(Direction~Lag1+Lag2, data = Smarket, family = binomial, subset = train)
glm.probs = predict(glm.fits, Smarket.2005, type = "response")
glm.pred = rep("Down", 252)
glm.pred[glm.probs > .5] = "Up"
table(glm.pred, Direction.2005)
mean(glm.pred == Direction.2005) # 55.95 correct predictions for train
mean(glm.pred != Direction.2005)
```

Comment: The code is not reproducible since we don't have `train`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas Just updated the code.

Comment: `tbl <- table(Smarket.2005$Direction, glm.probs > thresh)` and then `spc <- tbl[1, 1]/sum(tbl[1,])`. You should also see package `caret`, it's probably the most used package for this type of problems.

Comment: Thanks. It says object "thresh" not found.

Comment: If I calculate it manually, will it be simply: true negative / false positive ?

Comment: No, it's TN/(TN + FP). And `thresh` is your chosen threshold, say, `thresh <- 0.5`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224276/discussion-between-rook-and-rui-barradas).

Comment: Ok, I am getting it now. However, when I ran your code, I noticed the table values for the matrix got swapped into [77,34][97,44]. Is this the correct representation of [TN,FP][FN,TP]? Because from my code table(glm.pred, Direction.2005), it produces the matrix order of [77,97][34,44].

Comment: You are swapping `glm.pred` and `Direction.2005`.